How to Correctly Categorize and Calculate Ratios for Continuous and Categorical Data in Python Without Pandas?
I'm working on a cardiovascular disease dataset analysis in Python, but I cannot use Pandas. The goal is to categorize attributes like height, weight, systolic blood pressure (ap_hi), and diastolic blood pressure (ap_lo) into 5 equal-width bins, calculate ratios between those with and without cardio problems for each bin, and only keep ratios strictly greater than 1.
I also need to handle categorical attributes like cholesterol, glucose, smoking, drinking, and activity. The challenge is accurately creating these bins, calculating the ratios, and ensuring the output matches the expected results (which are provided below).
My Approach:

Filtering invalid data: I remove records with out-of-bound values for height, weight, ap_hi, and ap_lo.

Bin Creation: I calculate bins for continuous attributes (e.g., systolic blood pressure) and ensure max boundaries don't exclude any data points.

Ratio Calculation: For each bin, I calculate the ratio of people with a cardio problem vs. those without.

Handling Categorical Data: For attributes like cholesterol, glucose, smoking, drinking, and activity, I calculate the ratio for each category.


Here’s my complete code:
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

# Function to filter data based on the provided conditions
def filter_data(data):
    filtered_data = []
    for row in data:
        if not row['height'] or not row['weight'] or not row['ap_hi'] or not row['ap_lo']:
            continue  # Skip rows with missing essential values
        
        height = int(row['height'])
        weight = float(row['weight'])
        ap_hi = int(row['ap_hi'])
        ap_lo = int(row['ap_lo'])
        
        # Apply filtering conditions with 'or' to exclude invalid records
        if height < 150 or height > 200 or weight < 50 or weight > 150 or ap_hi < 80 or ap_hi > 200 or ap_lo < 70 or ap_lo > 140:
            continue  # Ignore this record if any condition is met
        
        filtered_data.append(row)
    
    return filtered_data

# Helper function to create bins for continuous attributes
def create_bins(data, attribute, num_bins=5, max_adjustment=0.1):
    min_val = min(float(row[attribute]) for row in data)
    max_val = max(float(row[attribute]) for row in data) + max_adjustment  # Adjust upper bound to avoid boundary issues
    bin_width = (max_val - min_val) / num_bins
    return [min_val + i * bin_width for i in range(num_bins + 1)]  # Return list of bin edges

# Function to calculate the bin index for a value
def get_bin_index(value, bin_edges):
    for i in range(len(bin_edges) - 1):
        if bin_edges[i] <= value < bin_edges[i + 1]:
            return i
    return len(bin_edges) - 2  # Assign the highest value to the last bin

# Main function to analyze the data and compute ratios
def analyse(gender, age):
    # Load data from CSV file
    data = []
    with open('cardio_train.csv', 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=';')
        for row in reader:
            data.append(row)

    # Filter data based on the correct conditions
    filtered_data = filter_data(data)
    
    # Further filter by gender and age
    gender_value = 2 if gender == 'F' else 1
    filtered_data = [row for row in filtered_data if int(row['gender']) == gender_value and int(row['age']) // 365 == age]

    if not filtered_data:
        print(f"No data available for {gender.lower()}s aged {age}.")
        return

    # Split data into cardio problem and no cardio problem classes
    cardio_yes = [row for row in filtered_data if int(row['cardio']) == 1]
    cardio_no = [row for row in filtered_data if int(row['cardio']) == 0]

    # Labels for attributes
    attribute_labels = {
        'height': "Height in category",
        'weight': "Weight in category",
        'ap_hi': "Systolic blood pressure in category",
        'ap_lo': "Diastolic blood pressure in category",
        'cholesterol': "Cholesterol in category",
        'gluc': "Glucose in category"
    }

    # Create bins for continuous attributes
    bins = defaultdict(list)
    for attr in ['height', 'weight', 'ap_hi', 'ap_lo']:
        bins[attr] = create_bins(filtered_data, attr)

    # Calculate ratios for continuous attributes
    ratios = []
    for attr in ['height', 'weight', 'ap_hi', 'ap_lo']:
        for i in range(len(bins[attr]) - 1):
            yes_count = sum(1 for row in cardio_yes if bins[attr][i] <= float(row[attr]) < bins[attr][i + 1])
            no_count = sum(1 for row in cardio_no if bins[attr][i] <= float(row[attr]) < bins[attr][i + 1])

            if yes_count + no_count < 5:
                continue  # Skip bins with too few data points

            if no_count > 0:
                ratio = yes_count / no_count
                if ratio > 1:
                    ratios.append((ratio, f"{attribute_labels[attr]} {i + 1} (1 lowest, {len(bins[attr]) - 1} highest)", attr, i + 1))
            elif yes_count > 0:
                ratios.append((float('inf'), f"{attribute_labels[attr]} {i + 1} (1 lowest, {len(bins[attr]) - 1} highest)", attr, i + 1))

    # Process categorical attributes (cholesterol, glucose, smoking, drinking, activity)
    for attr in ['cholesterol', 'gluc', 'smoke', 'alco', 'active']:
        yes_count = defaultdict(int)
        no_count = defaultdict(int)
        for row in cardio_yes:
            yes_count[int(row[attr])] += 1
        for row in cardio_no:
            no_count[int(row[attr])] += 1

        for value in yes_count:
            if value in no_count and no_count[value] > 0:
                ratio = yes_count[value] / no_count[value]
                if ratio > 1:
                    if attr in ['cholesterol', 'gluc']:
                        category = f"{attribute_labels[attr]} {value} (1 lowest, 3 highest)"
                    else:
                        category = (f"{'Being active' if attr == 'active' else 'Smoking' if attr == 'smoke' else 'Drinking'}"
                                    if int(value) == 1 else
                                    f"Not being active" if attr == 'active' else f"Not smoking" if attr == 'smoke' else f"Not drinking")
                    ratios.append((ratio, category, attr, int(value)))
            elif yes_count[value] > 0:
                if attr in ['cholesterol', 'gluc']:
                    category = f"{attribute_labels[attr]} {value} (1 lowest, 3 highest)"
                else:
                    category = (f"{'Being active' if attr == 'active' else 'Smoking' if attr == 'smoke' else 'Drinking'}"
                                if int(value) == 1 else
                                f"Not being active" if attr == 'active' else f"Not smoking" if attr == 'smoke' else f"Not drinking")
                ratios.append((float('inf'), category, attr, int(value)))

    # Sort ratios from largest to smallest, prioritizing by attribute and then by bin/category number
    all_attributes = ['height', 'weight', 'ap_hi', 'ap_lo', 'cholesterol', 'gluc', 'smoke', 'alco', 'active']
    ratios.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[0], all_attributes.index(x[2]), x[3]))

    # Print formatted ratios
    if ratios:
        print(f"The following might particularly contribute to cardio problems for {'females' if gender == 'F' else 'males'} aged {age}:")
        for ratio, description, _, _ in ratios:
            ratio_str = 'inf' if ratio == float('inf') else f"{ratio:.2f}"
            print(f"   {ratio_str}: {description}")

# Example usage
analyse('F', 43)

Issues I'm Facing:

Bin Categorization: Some values like systolic blood pressure (ap_hi) or diastolic blood pressure (ap_lo) are not always categorized correctly. For example, values that should fall into category 5 are sometimes placed in category 3.

Ratio Mismatch: The calculated ratios don’t match the expected results, especially for extreme values. For instance, I expect 17.88 for Diastolic Blood Pressure in Category 4, but I'm getting a much lower value (11.25).

Max Value Handling: I'm using a small max_adjustment (0.1) to avoid boundary issues, but I'm still getting miscategorized values for high bins.


Expected Output:
For example, the expected output for females aged 43 looks like this:
The following might particularly contribute to cardio problems for females aged 43:
   17.88: Diastolic blood pressure in category 4 (1 lowest, 5 highest)
   12.46: Systolic blood pressure in category 1 (1 lowest, 5 highest)
   9.98: Diastolic blood pressure in category 3 (1 lowest, 5 highest)
   8.53: Cholesterol in category 3 (1 lowest, 3 highest)
   3.99: Diastolic blood pressure in category 2 (1 lowest, 5 highest)
   3.25: Diastolic blood pressure in category 5 (1 lowest, 5 highest)
   2.44: Height in category 5 (1 lowest, 5 highest)
   2.11: Glucose in category 3 (1 lowest, 3 highest)
   2.09: Weight in category 4 (1 lowest, 5 highest)
   2.09: Systolic blood pressure in category 5 (1 lowest, 5 highest)
   1.79: Systolic blood pressure in category 4 (1 lowest, 5 highest)
   1.60: Cholesterol in category 2 (1 lowest, 3 highest)
   1.43: Glucose in category 2 (1 lowest, 3 highest)
   1.35: Not being active
   1.25: Weight in category 3 (1 lowest, 5 highest)
   1.20: Systolic blood pressure in category 2 (1 lowest, 5 highest)
   1.03: Height in category 2 (1 lowest, 5 highest)
   1.03: Height in category 3 (1 lowest, 5 highest)
   1.02: Not smoking
   1.01: Drinking

The output I got:
The following might particularly contribute to cardio problems for females aged 43:
   11.25: Diastolic blood pressure in category 3 (1 lowest, 5 highest)
   6.00: Systolic blood pressure in category 5 (1 lowest, 5 highest)
   4.72: Systolic blood pressure in category 3 (1 lowest, 5 highest)
   4.67: Weight in category 4 (1 lowest, 5 highest)
   4.00: Weight in category 5 (1 lowest, 5 highest)
   4.00: Diastolic blood pressure in category 4 (1 lowest, 5 highest)
   3.50: Systolic blood pressure in category 4 (1 lowest, 5 highest)
   3.00: Cholesterol in category 3 (1 lowest, 3 highest)
   2.08: Diastolic blood pressure in category 2 (1 lowest, 5 highest)
   1.57: Weight in category 3 (1 lowest, 5 highest)
   1.38: Height in category 5 (1 lowest, 5 highest)
   1.18: Glucose in category 3 (1 lowest, 3 highest)
   1.10: Cholesterol in category 2 (1 lowest, 3 highest)

Question:

How can I ensure that binning captures the correct data ranges, especially for extreme values in continuous attributes?

How can I tweak the ratio calculations to better match the expected output?

Are there better ways to handle edge cases and ensure the max boundary is correctly accounted for?


Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated!
